# What's the best way to find words in multiples files with Vim

Tags: vim

I use Vim for coding for years, mostly with [NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) to handle easily a big project with multiple files - like a MVC framework.

But i faced regulary a issue, how to find words, sentences, keywords in files into the project? All the files aren't open in buffers.
I used to make it with this find & grep command in the terminal but it's need me to put vim in hte background, copy the name of the files and go back to vim.

> find . -type f -name *.js -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i foo

Not really userfriendly...

Is there a better/faster way to do this ?

Comment: I'm interested to know this myself. What I usually do is issue this from shell: `vim $(grep -lR foo *)`, which doesn't really solve the issue of doing it interactely from within vim.

Comment: Try `:help grep`  Internal vimgrep even allows for searches across line boundaries.  Keep an eye to the "starstar" wildcard for scanning entire trees.

Comment: @BrianTiffin What if i got multiples macthes ? VimGrep seems to stop and display only the first one

Comment: @x_vi_r Try adding "g" after the match criteria.

Comment: :vim /foo/i `git ls-files "*.js"` | cw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to do that:

- you can use `:vimgrep` to do grep
- you can call external grep
- you can install vim ack plugin: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim (I am using this one)

with `:vim` or ack plugin, the found file path+name would be listed in quickfix list, to let you jump to easily.

also I have written a script to do "grep" again on quickfix list, may helpful too:

https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep

Comment: Can you be more precise of the reasons of your choice Ack vs grep ?

Comment: no special reason, @x_vi_r Ack is easier to search source codes file types, well I am not saying grep cannot do that.  here is the `why ack` page:  http://beyondgrep.com/why-ack/  In terminal, I am still using grep...:)  Also there is another screencast of using grep/vimgrep in vim, you may want to watch: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/

Comment: How do you use the Ack plugin ? `Ack -i foo /myDir` Don't return anything here ... Igot files with "foo" inside :)

Comment: @x_vi_r if you are about to use ack plugin, have you read the linked page in my answer? there should be detailed installation/usage guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can run external commands using r:

```
:r! command-to-run
```

You could use your existing find command with this:

```
:r! find . -type f -name *.js -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i foo
```

The output of running this command will be inserted into your current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is this:

```
:split
:enew
:r!find . -type f -name *.js -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i foo
```

Which will display the results in a new buffer. If you add

```
:set buftype=nofile
```

Then it will turn it into a scratch buffer and you can just `:q!` it with no fanfare.